# What roles and permissions are needed to invite users to Azure app?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Using .NET framework and the MS graph API to create a user invite in Azure AAD.
I am getting insufficient privileges when creating an invitation.
What do I (my IT) need to do to have privileges to do this?
I have the Guest Inviter Role as the only administrator role.
I only have the Microsoft Graph permission for my app.
Do I need other permissions in the apps to create an invite?

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark the answer by clicking the arrow and verify by clicking the emoji below. Doing so helps others find answers to their related questions

Answer (score 0):

The application needs to have atleast one of the MS Graph API permissions [User.Invite.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) or if the application wants to invoke the invitation api as signed-in user, then the application should acquire token for graph end point with "[Directory.AccessAsUser.All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#directory-permissions)" permission.